# How to reference implicit parameters in a where closure

Tags: grails, grails-orm, implicit-parameters

How can I use an implicit parameter inside a `where` closure?

I'm not especially proud of my current workaround:

```
def index() {
    def params = params                 // <-- UGLY HACK
    respond Project.where {
        if (params.sender) {
            sender.id == params.sender  // <-- OTHERWISE THIS WOULD FAIL
        }
    }
}
```

Also I noticed that I can parameterize the query by putting generic Groovy code inside the closure, such as the `if` above. Strangely, the `params` inside the conditional did not cause any trouble, even without the hack. Is this practice OK or is it discouraged?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get the `sender` first:

```
def thesender = Sender.get(params.sender)
```

Then pass it as criteria to your `where` closure:

```
Project.where { sender == thesender }
```

You get Something like this:

```
def index() {
    def thesender = Sender.get(params.sender)

    respond Project.where { sender == thesender }
}
```